# Error: incompatible types: ActionProvider cannot be converted to ShareActionProvider

Tags: android

```
   package com.example.ch_m_usman.example;

   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.widget.TextView;  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       private ShareActionProvider actionProvider;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           String msg = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
           if (msg != null){
               TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgdisplay);
               tv.setText(msg);
           }

       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);


           MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.share_action);
           actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();//here i got error
           return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       }

       private void setIntent(String text){
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           intent.setType("text/plain");
           intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,text);
           actionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
       }
       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

           int id = item.getItemId();


           if (id == R.id.setting) {
               Intent intent = new   Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
               String msg = "Welcome to Second Activity";
               intent.putExtra("msg", msg);
               startActivity(intent);
           }

           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   }
```

Comment: post `menu_main.xml` file here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach to solving this.

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

And add:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.share_action) {
           startShareIntent();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

And:

```
    @Override
public void startShareIntent(String link) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, link);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.share)));
}
```

Pretty much self-explanatory. This way you have more control of behaviour after clicking share button.